# Ubuntu 12.04 live CD not booting on iMac G5 (Intel)

Tags: 12.04, boot, bluetooth, mac

My iMac G5 isnt booting the Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD (32 bit version). When I press the up key, the last line is "* Starting bluetooth daemon". It does not have the [OK] next to it. If I dont press the up, the animation eventually freezes and the ubuntu logo and dots just hang on the screen. Is there anyway I can skip the bluetooth daemon? Or any other solutions?

Comment: Are you using the PowerPC iso or the i386?

Comment: i386. Its got the Intel Processor

Comment: Could you try booting with `modprobe.blacklist=bluez,bluetooth,btusb` ? Throw em in on the same line, but right before `quiet splash`. Should disable the bluetooth, if i've got the module name correct. :p

Comment: Also, if you're running an Intel machine and not PPC, why not try 14.04? Might have better luck booting with the newer kernel.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how to boot with those args? Im kind of an idiot when it comes to Ubuntu. And the software Ill be using requires 12.04, so thats what Im bound to using.

Comment: choose boot option, press <kbd>e</kbd>, find string contains `quiet spalsh`, replace `quiet spalsh` with `modprobe.blacklist=bluez,bluetooth,btusb quiet spalsh`, press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot configuration.

Comment: No problem. Let us know if that helps out.

Comment: Ok, I did that, and it got passes starting bluetooth daemon. But it got stuck at Starting Uncomplicated firewall :P

Answer (score 0):

- choose boot option
- press <kbd>e</kbd>
- find string contains `quiet spalsh`
- replace `quiet spalsh` with `modprobe.blacklist=bluez,bluetooth,btusb quiet spalsh`
- press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot configuration

Comment: Ok, I did that, and it got passes starting bluetooth daemon. But it got stuck at Starting Uncomplicated firewall :P

Comment: so, do you have boot installer?